# sql file add table prefix

Tags: mysql, database, prefix

I have imported one `sql file` from MySQL(phpmyadmin), in that I have almost `200 tables` with their data. Now I want to import that sql file in another location. But there is one change in my sql file before importing. I have to use `'tbl_' prefix` before all the tables. So if the table name was `admin_config` this will be like `tbl_admin_config` in new location . As I have `200 tables` in the sql file so changine prefix manually one by one is very time taking. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this in a cleaver way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope your syntax is like below for the insert queries.

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( field1, field2,...fieldN )
                   VALUES
                   ( value1, value2,...valueN );
```

Then you can replace all "INSERT INTO " with "INSERT INTO tbl_" using a text editor to support your new tables before executing the Script.